# Bind WPF DataGridTemplateColumnn ComboBox after page had loaded

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am having problems binding to a DataGridTemplateColumn column on my  control. I've read several posts about this, but none seem to be working properly for me, possibly because of the application architecture - I'm not sure. Binding to the DataGridTextColumn works, but the ComboBox I have defined inside the template column is blank. I have this XAML snippet::

```
    <jibcontrols:JibGrid x:Name="UsersDataGrid">
...
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=Role}" ItemsSource="{Binding Item, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" DisplayMemberPath="Role"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Role}"></DataGridTextColumn>
...
```

We are using a message bus architecture, so the data source is not ready when the page initially loads. After the data is returned from the service, a method is called to populate the DataGrid:

```
    private void UpdateGrid(Users o)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var entities = o.OrderBy(e => e.Role);

            UsersDataGrid.FilteredItemsSource = entities;
            UsersDataGrid.DataContext = entities;
        });
    }
```

What have I gotten wrong in this scenario?

Comment: Where do you define the options to choose from in the `ComboBox`? What's the type of these? And what is `Item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through a [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/combobox-in-datagrid-in-wpf/) and saw what I was doing wrong. There were a couple things, but how I resolved it was creating a custom class with the values I needed (there were only two):

```
public class RoleList : List<string>
{
    public RoleList()
    {
        this.Add("Administrator");
        this.Add("Operator");
    }
}
```

Next, I added the namespace where the class resided:

```
xmlns:dm="clr-namespace:Coasters.ViewModels"
```

I then added a Page.Resources tag to hold my new data source:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <dm:RoleList x:Key="RoleList" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Last but not least, I actually configured the ComboBox correctly (always a useful thing to do), using the ItemsSource pointing to my data source, and the SelectedItem pointing to the class property that holds the "Role" field:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource RoleList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Role}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```